# Summing attribute values from many points geocoded on same location using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geolocation, summarizing

I have geocoded a batch of addresses and many of these are geocoded on the same location. Now I want to keep just one point on each location but sum the field values of all points from the same location. How I can do that using ArcGIS?

Comment: Try dissolve tool

Comment: Use the dissolve tool as @BERA suggested, the answer of converting it to a raster is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, dissolve tool will solve this on the best way, but @BERA should give the answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [dissolve](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm) tool:

> Aggregates features based on specified attributes

And:

> The attributes of the features that become aggregated by dissolve can
>   be summarized or described using a variety of statistics. The
>   statistic used to summarize attributes is added to the output feature
>   class as a single field with the naming standard of statistic type +
>   underscore + input field name.